# ng-repeat not working with onsen ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, onsen-ui

I'm going nuts, this is such a small thing but I can't find a solution...
I have this js file (the angularjs app is initialized in the begining of the html document)

```
app.controller('slidingMenuCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [
        {title: 'Festas', icon: 'ion-ios-pint', notifications: 3},
        {title: 'Palestras', icon: 'fa-microphone', notifications: 0}
    ];
    $scope.test = 'aaa';
});
```

and somewhere in my html

```
<ons-template id="menu.html" ng-controller="slidingMenuCtrl">
    <ons-page>
        <div ng-repeat="x in categories">
            {{x.title}}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{test}}
        </div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

The div with ng-repeat shows nothing, but the one without it shows 'aaa' correctly, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ons-template` template doesn't support `ng-controller` directive, basically it needs an idea to process a template and thereafter a processing if we ask for template over `http` it returns registered `ons-template` with that `id`, here you had `menu.html`

You could do same thing as that by having `script` tag with type `text/ons-template` there. Its just same as `type/ng-template` in angular.

**Template**

```
<script type="text/ons-template" id="main.html">

   ...content here...

</script>
```

Add `ng-controller` over `ons-page` will make it working by instantiating `controller` specified `ng-controller` directive.

**Code**

```
<ons-page ng-controller="slidingMenuCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in categories">
        {{x.title}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{test}}
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. I tried to call the controller in ons-page but the controller wasn't even recognized then. However I found the problem, I was initializing ons and angularjs separately and I shouldn't

Comment: @user3820203 but the code which you have added..has the problem which I rectified.. anyways. Thanks :)